# Wordpress and Laravel working together on NGINX

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx, nginx-config, vhosts

I'm trying to set up nginx vhost so I can use wordpress and laravel on the same domain.
I put wordpress in the root folder
And in a subfolder /laravel/ installed laravel

Is it possible to make that if for example laravel route /laravel-page in URL, request on server will not go to wordpress /index.php but to Laravel /laravel/public/index.php,
and all other pages are normally requested to /index.php
I would like to whitelist URLs using RegExp, which will be handled by Laravel.

**UPDATE:**
After a few experiments, I managed to get what I wanted. I added:

```
location ~ ^/laravel-page(?:/(.*))?$ {
    index /laravel/public/index.php;
}
```

These pages are now handled by Laravel: `/laravel-page/1333/`. But for some reason, if I enter the address without the slash `/laravel-page/1333` , it gives a 404 error, and not from wordpress or laravel, but the usual one from nginx. I tried adding a redirect:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

It works, but laravel doesn't open.

Comment: Yeah, why shouldn't that be possible? Please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: After a few experiments, I managed to get what I wanted. I added:
`location ~ ^/laravel-page(?:/(.*))?$ {
index /laravel/public/index.php;
}`
These pages are now handled by Laravel:
`/laravel-page/1333/`.
But for some reason, if I enter the address without the slash `/laravel-page/1333` , it gives a 404 error, and not from wordpress or laravel, but the usual one from nginx.  I tried adding a redirect:
`rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;`
It works, but laravel doesn't open.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all clarification - don't hide it in the comment section